# Display Illustrations created in illustrator

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to create a web application where designers can submit and share there work. But i figured not all designers would submit only jpeg's or gif's. So i am allowing options to submit their creations in .ai (Adobe Illustrator) format. But after the file is uploaded can i give any options to the users to view those illustrations. Is there any external application which i can use to give preview of such files.

I am developing in PHP, and using CakePHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageMagick seems to have support for .ai

http://www.imagemagick.org

Comment: You create the preview on the server!!! Take the .ai file, and use the CONVERT command to gen preview...

Comment: Sorry for accepting it so late. :) Seems like I skipped a couple of questions. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

They can save their files as SVG, which is a vector graphics file that won't loose quality on zoom.

Modern browsers can display SVG file, Wikipedia seems to use them a lot : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:SVG_Simple_Logo.svg

Comment: What do you exactly mean?

If you were talking about browser extensions, most modern browsers like Chrome, Safari, Firefox (even the lastest IE) can display SVG images without any kind of plug-in.

Adobe Illustrator can (at least I know CS3 and later are able to) produce files as SVG : http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-655b.html

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator natively has the ability to save as a PDF.

Comment: I've managed to do it with ImageMagick as @Adrian has suggested. The whole point was to share the original work between the artists. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with users submitting an .ai file is you can have many versions of the same design or document with varied layer combinations within the same document and endless combinations of these across various artboards (which can all be different sizes within the same document). I don't think doing this well is a matter of simply being able to display a certain file format or a preview of the document. As above I think it would be better to utilise other formats such as PDF, SVG or just make it simpler and educate them through the UI to save comps as PNG/JPG/SVG etc and make the ai available for download.